# Position absolute left 0 relative to window instead of parent

Tags: html, css

I am creating a header for my site using flex with an absolute positioned sub-menu. I want the sub-menu to span the entire width of the page but I want it to be flush with the left side of the window rather than the parent.

```css
header {
  display:flex;
  padding:0 15px;
  align-items:center;
}
  img.logo {
    flex-shrink:0;
    padding:16px 0;
    margin-right:30px;
  }
  nav {
    align-self:stretch;
  }
  ul {
    display:flex;
    height:100%;
    align-items:center;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
  }
    li {
      display:flex;
      position:relative;
      height:100%;
      margin-left:30px;
    }
      li > ul {
        height:20px;
        background:#ccc;
        position:absolute;
        width:100vw;
        left:0;
        bottom:-20px;
      }
      li:first-child {
        margin-left:0;
      }
      li a {
        display:flex;
        align-items:center;
        height:100%;
      }
```

```html
<header>
  <a href="#"><img class="logo" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/50/"/></a>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Parent 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Parent 2</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Child 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Child 2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Parent 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Parent 4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Instead of "Child 1" lining up with the left side of "Parent 2" I would like it to line up with the left side of the window.

Comment: let me know, you want to make that gray container of children to go anticlockwise or to position it under its parent vertically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your issue. Child 1 lines up flush with the left side of parent 2 because its a direct child, so when we specify `position: absolute` and `left: 0` its doing so, but positioning at the left of Parent 2.

I gave the sub menu `<ul>` of Parent 2 an id selector and then set `position: fixed` and added `left: 0` for content to be flush with the left side of the window. You can modify the `top` position to whatever you'd like, I set it to 100px in order to mimic the photo you included.

Try this out.

```css
header {
  display:flex;
  padding:0 15px;
  align-items:center;
}
  img.logo {
    flex-shrink:0;
    padding:16px 0;
    margin-right:30px;
  }
  nav {
    align-self:stretch;
  }
  ul {
    display:flex;
    height:100%;
    align-items:center;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
  }
    li {
      display:flex;
      position:relative;
      height:100%;
      margin-left:30px;
    }
      li > ul {
        height:20px;
        background:#ccc;
        position:absolute;
        width:100vw;
        left:0;
        bottom:-20px;
      }
      li:first-child {
        margin-left:0;
      }
      li a {
        display:flex;
        align-items:center;
        height:100%;
      }
      
      #child-row {
        position: fixed;
        top: 100px;
        left: 0;
      }
```

```html
<header>
  <a href="#"><img class="logo" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/50/"/></a>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Parent 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Parent 2</a>
        <ul id="child-row">
          <li><a href="#">Child 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Child 2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Parent 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Parent 4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this code for your nav and *

```
 * {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

nav {
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
}
```

After that you can adjust interface manually.